# Ckeditor 4.4.7 Can't Load In Master Page

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor, master-pages

I tried Ckeditor 4.4.7 in normal pages without Master Page.

But when I tried using Master Page, Ckeditor 4.4.7 can't load into the Child Page.

I tried placing the Javascript into my Child Page but it still can't load.

```html
                <script src="ckeditor_4.4.7_standard/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Post the url of a page from where you're trying to access it and also the folder structure in which you're keeping the ckeditor js